A list appearing within a scroll is being cut off
I make a list appear, with absolute position, of some buttons. This list is behind a div above, making the list cut off. I already tried to z-index the list and the div that is in front, but it didn't work.
Link with example:
https://codepen.io/pedrocardogiiromaps/pen/YzMojoe
Sorry my english, i don't speak english.


const priorities = document.getElementsByClassName('priority-button');

const arrayPriorities = Array.from(priorities);

arrayPriorities.forEach(function(element) {
  element.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    const nextElement = element.nextElementSibling;
    if (nextElement.classList.contains('hidden')) {
      nextElement.classList.remove('hidden');
    } else {
      nextElement.classList.add('hidden');
    }

    const position = getPositionRelativeToPage(nextElement);
    const windowHeight = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight;

    //if (position > windowHeight * 0.5) {
    nextElement.style.bottom = `${windowHeight - windowHeight * 0.95}px`;
    //}
  });
});

function getPositionRelativeToPage(element) {
  const rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
  const scrollTop = window.scrollY;
  return rect.top + scrollTop;
}
.lanes {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: start;
  gap: 16px;
  padding: 24px 32px;
  overflow: scroll;
  height: 100%;
}

.container-prioridades {
  position: relative;
}

.prioridades {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
<div class="lanes">
  <div class="" id="">
    <div style="width: 100%; display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">
      <h3 class="heading">TODO</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="swim-lane" id="todo-lane" style="max-height: 200px; overflow-y: auto; overflow-y: scroll;">
      <div class="task" draggable="true">
        Get groceries
        <div class="container-prioridades">
          <button class="priority-button">prioridades</button>
          <div class="prioridades hidden" style="z-index: 100;">
            <button>1</button>
            <button>1</button>
            <button>1</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="task" draggable="true">
        Feed the dogs
        <div class="container-prioridades">
          <button class="priority-button">priorities</button>
          <div class="prioridades hidden" style="z-index: 100;">
            <button>1</button>
            <button>1</button>
            <button>1</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="task" draggable="true">
        Mow the lawn
        <div style="display: flex;align-items: center;">
          <div class="container-prioridades">
            <button class="priority-button">prioridades</button>
            <div class="prioridades hidden" style="z-index: 100;">
              <button>1</button>
              <button>1</button>
              <button>1</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



I tried using z-index, isolation, fixed and nothing helped.

You set a max-height so the div is blocked to this height, so due to your inline css, scrollbar appears

Given that the HTML is following the explicit dimensions you've set in the CSS, I can't see what other outcome you expect to have?

"This list is behind a div above, making the list cut off" - no, no it's not.  It's in its own scrollable region (in the codepen there's no scrollbar).  Add style border:20px rebeccapurple solid; and you'll see it's not going behind the "todo" div.   Also remove the ridiculous scrollbar-width: none which kills the UX and is confusing you.
